# I am trying to set left margin in my document but I am unable to do it

Tags: margins

I am using:

`\oddsidemargin -.1in
\evensidemargin 1in`

**oddsidemargin** is able to control right-hand side margin while for **evensidemargin** there is no effect. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: the default in article is `oneside` so all pages use the same (odd) setting, use `[twoside]` documentclass option to enable double sided setting It is better to use geometry package , or at least use latex syntax `\setlength` to set the page size.

Comment: Are you using TeX or LaTeX? In the later case: Use the `geometry` package in order to change page layout parameters and do not change `\oddsidemargin` etc. directly